# In Postgres, after truncating or deleting rows, does executing reindex before pg_dump optimize pg_restore?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-dump, reindex, pg-restore

Do the `REINDEX` statements below help with the restore operation or file size of the dump?

Could not find a question about this anywhere on SO or web. I'm using Postgres 9.4 and cleaning out a very large database with both `truncate` and `delete` statements on various tables.

The table data varies in type and size.

After this clean up operation, I immediately execute a pg_dump, tar and upload, then pg_restore. It's using the directory format with 12 jobs in parallel for dump, 8 for restore.

For example, these queries first:

```
TRUNCATE users;
DELETE FROM users_email WHERE active = 1;

REINDEX TABLE users;
REINDEX TABLE users_email;
```

Then:

```bash
$ pg_dump_9.4 --compress=0 -F directory -j 12 $DB_EXPORT_NAME -f $DB_DUMP_FOLDER 2>> operations.log

$ # do tar and upload with dump then:

$ pg_restore_9.4 -d $DB_IMPORT_NAME -j 8 $DB_DUMP_FOLDER 2>> operations.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make no difference at all for `pg_dump` or `pg_restore`.

`pg_dump` doesn't use the index at all, it just writes its definition as a `CREATE INDEX` statement into the dump. The table itself is scanned sequentially.

`pg_restore` creates the index using the `CREATE INDEX` from the dump.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: No, but it is obvious from the way it is implemented. Just look at a dump - it contains a `CREATE INDEX` statement. You only need the metadata to get that.